# Snap Shot of Individual Eyes

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have detected eyes using this code:

```
MCvAvgComp[][] eyes = gray1.DetectHaarCascade(eye, 1.1, 1, 
       Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
gray1.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
foreach (MCvAvgComp eyesnap in eyes[0])
{
    Rectangle eyeRect = eyesnap.rect;
    eyeRect.Offset(f.rect.X, f.rect.Y);
    nextFrame.Draw(eyeRect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);
}
```

I want to take snapshot of both eyes in different picturebox. Can any one help me understand how I can take a snapshot of individual eyes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *GetSubRect* function to get sub image:

```
IImage eyeImg = nextFrame.GetSubRect(eyeRect);
```

Or

```
Bitmap eyeBmp = nextFrame.GetSubRect(eyeRect).Bitmap;
```

**Edit**

Load *HaarCascade* for left eye:

```
HaarCascade leftEye = new HaarCascade("leftEye.xml");

MCvAvgComp[][] foundLeftEyes = gray1.DetectHaarCascade(leftEye, 1.1, 1, 
       Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
gray1.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
foreach (MCvAvgComp eyesnap in foundLeftEyes[0])
{
    Rectangle eyeRect = eyesnap.rect;
    eyeRect.Offset(f.rect.X, f.rect.Y);
    nextFrame.Draw(eyeRect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);
}
```

Same will be for right eye...

As an example you can use:

[Left eye HaarCascade](https://github.com/nzaillian/Qt-OpenCV-Integration-Demo/blob/master/resources/eye_left.xml) and [Right eye HaarCascade](https://raw.github.com/nzaillian/Qt-OpenCV-Integration-Demo/master/resources/eye_right.xml)

Comment: okkk. thnx for this. but from that how can it decide that which eye picture is captured. I tried this but it takes left eye snap. for right eye snap what code to write? plz help

Comment: In your case eye is HaarCascade object which is loaded from file. You need another HaarCascade object for second eye.

Comment: For example there are resources for both eyes: https://github.com/nzaillian/Qt-OpenCV-Integration-Demo/tree/master/resources